# Function of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, integration

I'm not exactly sure how an integral might be useful here. Somehow this question I will be asking is supposed to be related to bounded linear functionals but I'm still not seeing how.
Let a function $f$ belong to $C[a,b]$. We want to show that there's a function $g$ of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ for which $\displaystyle \int_a^b$$f(x)dg(x)$ = $\|f\|_{max}$ and $TV(g)$ = $1$, where $TV$ is the total variation of $g$. Could we begin by the fact that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and assume we have a function of bounded variation $g$ on $[a,b]$, and hence, $g$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$? I would really appreciate some help here, since I have been struggling with this for quite a while.

Comment: Absolute continuity implies bounded variation, not the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: try a step function with two values.

Comment: Would we be considering $g$ as a step function with two values?

Comment: @Jonas I deleted my previous comments because they were misguided and distracted from this fine answer.  I hope this is OK with you.

Answer (score 2):

Robert Israel has already indicated a much better answer than that which I am writing.  Here is an overkill answer, just for fun.

As an application of the Hahn-Banach theorem (e.g., see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34455/using-hahn-banach-in-proving-result-about-operators-and-their-adjoints-on-banach/34456#34456)), there is a bounded linear functional $\phi\in C[a,b]^*$ such that $\|\phi\|=1$ and $\phi(f)=\|f\|_\text{max}$.  The dual space $C[a,b]^*$ is isometrically isomorphically identified as the space of left-continuous functions of bounded variation vanishing at $a$ with total variation norm, $\|g\|=\mathrm{TV}(g)$, where the functional corresponding to $g$ is the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $f\mapsto \int_a^bfdg$ (e.g., see [pages 12-19 of Douglas's *Banach algebra techniques in operator theory*](http://books.google.com/books?id=-OdfXeNmrT0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA12#v=onepage&q&f=false)).  The result follows.